# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/myrepl/index.js:10:6

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I'm really new to Javascript. So please bear with my garbage coding but I do not know what this error means and have spent really long trying to solve this. I am using Replit right now but I have also tried it on Visual Studio which gives the same error. Please help, I have no idea what to do!

Whenever I try to run my script it keeps erroring with this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/myrepl/index.js:10:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Here Is my Index.js:

```
var prefix = 'p!'

args.forEach((a, b) => {
  args[b] = a.replace("`", "")

  args[b] = args[b].replace(".", "")

  args[b] = args[b].replace("`", "")
  args[b] = args[b].replace(`"`, "")

  args[b] = args[b].replace(`'`, "")

})
var args = Message.content.split(" ")
if (Message.author.bot == false) {
  if (Message.content.startsWith("$")) {

    if (Message.channel.id != CMDS && Message.author.id != DISCORD_ID) {
      Message.reply("stop using cmds here idiot. <#" + CMDS + ">")
    }
  }
```

I have Node.js, discord.js, discord, and npm installed. My bot token is stored in token.json and my config (discord_ID and CMDS channel ID is stored in config.json).

I am trying to make it controlled from discord with a command like "p!". I don't know this problem at all.

Comment: I'm assuming it's erroring with `args.forEach()`. `args` doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: how would I be able to fix this?

Comment: You define `args` after you use it.  Move the definition `var args = Message.content.split(" ")` above the `args.forEach` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through the args array (`args.forEach()`) before `var args` exists. If you move `var args = Message.content.split(" ")` just after `var prefix = 'p!'` (before your loop) then the issue presented should be solved. I couldn't say whether your code will then 'work', but it is why you are getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You currently have `args.forEach((a, b)..` twice. Before and after defining `args`. Remove the first one.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues that I see from the get-go is, you are iterating `args` before you declare the variable

```
--> iteration args.forEach((a, b) => {
  args[b] = a.replace("`", "")

  args[b] = args[b].replace(".", "")

  args[b] = args[b].replace("`", "")
  args[b] = args[b].replace(`"`, "")

  args[b] = args[b].replace(`'`, "")

})
 --> declaration var args = Message.content.split(" ")
```

it should be the other way around, like that:

```
--> declaration var args = Message.content.split(" ")

--> iteration args.forEach((a, b) => {
 args[b] = a.replace("`", "")

 args[b] = args[b].replace(".", "")

 args[b] = args[b].replace("`", "")
 args[b] = args[b].replace(`"`, "")

 args[b] = args[b].replace(`'`, "")

})
```

second this that i noticed is,
[.split is a method used on strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
and
[forEach is a method used on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

strictly for the error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
```

that error means that you can not iterate an undefined variable.
mainly because, as I explained up here, you try to iterate `args` before declaring such a variable. although, in order to you `.forEach()`, `args` must be an `Array`.

perhaps you could try and give more details? perhaps a link to a repository or at least show the data structure that you are using